# Allowing iPadOS screen rotation with UIRequiresFullScreen

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation

I'm making an app that should support both landscape and portrait orientation, but that should not support multitasking (split view).

I've tried to enable every orientation and the "Requires full screen" box to prevent multitasking, however the app starts in portrait (even if the current iPad orientation is Landscape) and it cannot be rotated.

[image]

The only way to make the rotation working is to disable "Requires full screen", however in this case it allows multitasking and I don't want it.

Therefore as far as I know there are only two choices:

-No rotation and no multitasking

-Rotation and multitasking

How can I enable rotation but not multitasking?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing the quoted AppDelegate method to solve your problem. My app is starting in landscape mode on iPads in Landscape by setting same info.plist values. (+ no multitasking)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {}
```